# Spring 3.1.1 form tag not using formatter/converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, converters, formatter

I have a following enum type:

```
public enum SearchLocationTypes {REGISTRATION, WORKPLACE}
```

I have created both: converter and formatter for this enum + formatter annotation factory (just in case).

Formatter:

```
public class SearchLocationTypesFormatter implements Formatter<SearchLocationTypes> {
    @Override
    public String print(SearchLocationTypes type, Locale locale) {
        String strType = "";
        switch(type) {
            case REGISTRATION: 
                strType = "rg";
                break;
            case WORKPLACE:
                strType = "wp";
                break;
        }
        return strType;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchLocationTypes parse(String strType, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        if(strType.equals("rg")) return SearchLocationTypes.REGISTRATION;
        if(strType.equals("wp")) return SearchLocationTypes.WORKPLACE;
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class SearchLocationTypesAnnotationFormatterFactory 
implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<SearchLocationTypesFormat> {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] {SearchLocationTypes.class}));
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(SearchLocationTypesFormat a, Class<?> type) {
        return new SearchLocationTypesFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(SearchLocationTypesFormat a, Class<?> type) {
        return new SearchLocationTypesFormatter();
    }

}
```

Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SearchLocationTypesFormat {}
```

Converter:

```
public class SearchLocationTypesConverter implements Converter<SearchLocationTypes, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(SearchLocationTypes type) {
        String strType = "";
        switch(type) {
            case REGISTRATION: 
                strType = "rg";
                break;
            case WORKPLACE:
                strType = "wp";
                break;
        }
        return strType;
    }

}
```

part of servlet.xml:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"  />
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="ru.riado.web.format.SearchLocationTypesConverter" />
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="formatters">
        <set>
            <bean class="ru.riado.web.format.SearchLocationTypesAnnotationFormatterFactory" />
            <bean class="ru.riado.web.format.SearchSortTypesFormatter" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When i invoke the following code from the JSP everything works just as expected.

Example:
Let's say i have a bean "form" with property "locType" that is set to 'REGISTRATION'.

```
public class Form {
  @SearchLocationTypesFormat
  private SearchLocationTypes locType;
  // setters and getters
}
```

Now, i'm using the following code and its output is "rg":

```
<s:eval expression="form.locType">
```

But spring form doesn't convert it's value to "rg". Instead of this it sets the value to "REGISTRATION", just as if it is using default converter. I tried to turn the default conversion off, but that didn't help.

Could anyone please tell me what i'm missing here?

Comment: Do you want to use `form.locType` in radio buttons or options? If yes, there's no need for converters (in Spring >= 3.0): https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3389

Comment: Yes, you're right, Xaerxess. But i want to understand why it is not working :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd refactor your code first:

```
public enum SearchLocationTypes {
  REGISTRATION("rg"),
  WORKPLACE("wp");

  private String abbr;

  SearchLocationTypes(String abbr) {
    this.abbr = abbr;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return abbr;
  }

  public static SearchLocationTypes fromString(String from) {
    for (SearchLocationTypes locType : SearchLocationTypes.values()) {
      if (locType.abbr.equals(from)) {
        return locType;
      }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```

and `Formatter` (and `Converter` same as print method):

```
public class SearchLocationTypesFormatter implements
    Formatter<SearchLocationTypes> {
  @Override
  public String print(SearchLocationTypes type, Locale locale) {
    return type == null ? "" : type.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public SearchLocationTypes parse(String strType, Locale locale)
      throws ParseException {
    return SearchLocationTypes.fromString(strType);
  }
}
```

Now you can use it in jsp with `form:radiobuttons` or `form:options`:

```
<form:select path="locType">
  <form:options />
</form:select>
```

*where by default the form value is the enum's name() and the form label is the enum's toString()* (from https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3389).

I can't check this out, but try `<s:eval expression="form.locType">` now.

Comment: I've tried your approach. Yes, it works, but not as expected :) Spring form tags are using toString() method to obtain the value for its fields from the enum, but not the parse() method of the appropriate formatter. So, looks like it is a, let's say, "feature" of the spring? BTW it's quite bad behaviour since domain object forced to store some views abbrs...